# Nested jQuery loop with Rails loop

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to nest a jQuery loop within a Rails loop but am not having any luck. The here is the rails:

```
<% entry.videos.each do |video| %>
    <input type="hidden" class="url" value="<%= video.url %>">
    <div class="videos" src=""></div>
<% end %>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.url').each(function () {
    var urlThumb = $.jYoutube($(this).val(), 'small');
    var url = $(this).val();
    $('.videos').append($('<div class="vidya"><a href="'+url+'" rel="prettyPhoto" class="youtubeLink"><img src="'+urlThumb+'" class="overlay"/></a></div>'));
            });
```

where jYoutube is just a method to grab a thumbnail from a youtube video.

The issue is that rather that inserting the thumbnail into the respective entry, it inserts all thumbnails into all entries with a video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use siblings function to filter the corrsponding div with videos class.

e.g:

```
$('.url').each(function(){
 var urlThumb = $.jYoutube($(this).val(), 'small');     
 var url = $(this).val();     
 $(this).siblings('.videos').append
 (
  $('<div class="vidya"><a href="'+url+'" rel="prettyPhoto" class="youtubeLink"><img src="'+urlThumb+'" class="overlay"/></a></div>')
 );    
});
```

Comment: It isn't combining all of the thumbails into each entry anymore, but for each entry that has more than 2 urls, it duplicates the links. So for 2 links, it outputs 4...

Answer (score 0):

Try this I am not sure

```
$('.url').each(function (index) {
    var urlThumb = $.jYoutube($(this).val(), 'small');
    var url = $(this).val();
    $('.videos').append($('<div class="vidya"><a href="'+url+'" rel="prettyPhoto" class="youtubeLink"><img src="'+urlThumb+'" class="overlay"/></a></div>'));
});
```

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything.